# How to replace space character with slash surrounded by spaces " / "?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using this code for replacing space with / in one of my fields.

```
  $('#field').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
  {  
    var myStr = $(this).val()
    myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "/");
    $('#field').val(myStr); 
  });
```

How can I add 2 spaces around "/"?

If I try to use `.replace(/\s+/g, " / ");` it gives me this `/ / / / / / / r` as i type.

Comment: Do you mean two spaces on either side like this: `"  /  "`?

Comment: Do you actually need to replace with `" / "`, or do you want to actually replace with `"/"`?

Comment: @ElGavilan, right. I need to have "stringspace/spacestring",  "qwe / rty"

Comment: You may try using your code with another regex: `myStr=myStr.replace(/(^|[^\/])\s+(?!\/\s)/g, "$1 / ");` Actually, keyup or kepress looks to be a redundant event here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#field').bind('keyup', function() {  
    var myStr = $(this).val()
    myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+$/g, ' / ');
    $('#field').val(myStr); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo62y4ja/3/

Added `$` to the regex and added spaces around `/` in replace value.  Also, reduced the key events to just `keyup`.

**EDIT:**

**anubhava** is right about using `keypress` instead of `keyup`.  Main difference is then adding the `$` in the regex.

Comment: anubhava has the same problem with his code as you. Did you check yours? Try typing this sequence: "any letter, space, any letter space..." a few times.

Comment: here's what I got by typing "q space q space q.."  ----->  "q  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  q  /  q"

Comment: Try the JSFiddle again.  For some reason the link was wrong.  It now contains the regex with $ in it.

Comment: btw, if I type something in text filed, then hit space and then start pressing ctrl or any other key like shift... - it'll type slash every time i press the button.

Comment: What about this: https://jsfiddle.net/uo62y4ja/4/.  It uses a regex to determine if the key should result in a /.  Can change the regex to allow more/less keys.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include `keyup` event otherwise replaced space also gets replaced by `"  /  "` repeatedly.

Following should work:

```
$('#field').bind('keypress', function() {  
    var myStr = $(this).val()
    myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "  /  ");
    $('#field').val(myStr); 
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uo62y4ja/1/)

Comment: try to type "q space q space" in your fiddle. It has the same problem. "q  /  /  /  q "